# while generating excel sheet report in mean while want to show Loading effect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show loading effect on click of a 'Generate report' button and i want to stop the loading effect when the report(excel sheet) is popup on screen.

Comment: Please read [ask], your request is too broad

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gif image representing a loading circle. It is visible between click and popup.

Comment: yeh i used the same gif image it is showing loading effect on click but it is not hiding when popup comes.

Comment: When reports loads you make image.visible = false;